# Overriding make variables containing spaces with MAKEFLAGS

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a bash script to run my Makefile-based project through Include-What-You-Use (IWYU) which looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MAKEFLAGS="-k CXX=iwyu -Xiwyu --transitive_includes_only -Xiwyu --mapping_file=qt5_4.imp"
build.sh
```

The `build.sh` script sets a couple of environment variables, prepares other parts of the build environment and will then eventually run `make`.

At first sight this seems to work and do its job. However closer inspection showed, that only `CXX=iwyu` is actually used in the build. The command line options for IWYU get dropped.

I tried various modifications of my call to fix this, however none seemed to solve the problem.

With

```
export MAKEFLAGS="-k CXX=iwyu\ -Xiwyu\ --transitive_includes_only\ -Xiwyu\ --mapping_file=qt5_4.imp"
```

the command line options are no longer dropped, but now suddenly `-k` seems to get dropped somewhere and my build (because of the missing `-k`) is terminated early with failure.

With

```
export MAKEFLAGS="-k CXX='iwyu -Xiwyu --transitive_includes_only -Xiwyu --mapping_file=qt5_4.imp'"
```

I'm flooded with `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` which looks like the ending `'` is somehow dropped.

Are there any other ways I have to escape and/or quote the spaces in my `export` to fix this?

Comment: Can you just do `export CXX='iwyu -Xiwyu --transitive_includes_only -Xiwyu --mapping_file=qt5_4.imp'` and use ${CXX} in the makefiles ?

Comment: @Philippe — does the setting in the environment override the setting in the makefile, if you try it that way?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If CXX is set in makefile, can we use CXX2 for example and test it in makefile to set it to CXX ?

Comment: @Philippe — you might be able to dink with the system like that with GNU Make, but not with classic (non-GNU) Make.  The 'passing MAKEFLAGS' technique is sometimes the best way to go.  That's a problem with relaying command line options in an original make to child make processes.  Using a script as I suggest avoids issues with quoting; the relaying is still a separate part of the problem.

Comment: @Philippe my focus was on trying to solve this command line argument/spaces problem, which is why I said it is Makefile-based. To be honest however, these Makefiles are currently generated with Qt's `qmake` and I don't have any direct means of changing them.

Comment: @Wegmann I encountered the same problem when passing MAKEFLAGS to override the existing flags. But I do not need `-k` option, so the solution via escaping space via `\ ` work for me. Thanks for your hint!!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a script (once?) to run `iwyu` — be careful, single quotes and double quotes are not interchangeable:

```
echo 'iwyu -Xiwyu --transitive_includes_only -Xiwyu --mapping_file=qt5_4.imp "$@"' > ./run.iwyu
chmod +x ./run.iwyu
```

and then run:

```
make -k CXX="$PWD/run.iwyu"
```

or:

```
export MAKEFLAGS="-k CXX=$PWD/run.iwyu"
```

This sidesteps the whole problem of spaces in the arguments.  As shown, you specify the full path for the `run.iwyu` script just in case your `make` process changes directories.  If you put the `run.iwyu` script in a directory on your `PATH`, you don't need to specify the full path to the script.  You could prefix the command line in the script with `exec` if you like.

Comment: Well, it isn't the answer to my question, but a solution to my problem :-) So, yeah, giving up the battle against make and do it this way in the end might be the best solution I can get.

Comment: This is really odd. I tried the approach using the wrapper script for iwyu and still failed. At the first call of an `ar` command `make` aborts  because the returned error is suddenly no longer ignored, `-k` seems to go missing. I found that adding a useless `-Xiwyu` after my script "fixes" the problem:
`export MAKEFLAGS="-k CXX=$PWD/run.iwyu -Xiwyu"`

Comment: Hmmm...that's tricky.  The basic idea was to avoid needing spaces in a single argument via the `MAKEFLAGS` setting.  I wrote `make CXX="$PWD/run.iwyu"`; I omitted a `-k` (`make -k CXX="$PWD/run.iwyu"`) — did you make that mistake too?  If so, I apologize for the oversight.

Comment: I have the `-k` in my `MAKEFLAGS="-k CXX=$PW/run.iwyu"`, so this should be ok I think. In the meantime I found even more weirdness. Adding anything of the form `-xy` as parameter to `run.iwyu` "fixes" the problem. The parameter isn't passed to `run.iwyu` but the errors are again properly ignored. Adding `-a` (only one-parameter argument) doesn't work, `--i` (double dash with single character) doesn't work. But anything like `-abcde`, `-Wasdf`, `-iii` seems to work.